# How to set a child view model and have it update html?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm new to knockout and I'm trying to set a child viewmodel after mapping some data using the mapping plugin.  I thought it would be as simple as setting in my sample, or the one below but neither work.  Any ideas?  I've setup a sample to help

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5VMF/2/)

```
viewModel.owner = ownerTwoViewModel;


viewModel.owner(ownerTwoViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewmodel.owner is not an observable property that is why it is not updating. so  make it observable.

```
var project = {
  title: "knockout",
  owner: ko.observable({
    name: 'Steve',
    title: 'Mr.'
  })
};
var ownerTwo = {
  name: 'Sarah',
  title: 'Mrs.'
};

//viewmodels
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(project);
var ownerTwoViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(ownerTwo);

//binding
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
//jquery event
$("#target").click(function () {
    viewModel.owner(ownerTwoViewModel);
});
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5VMF/5/)